# HTML email - issue with tables - Outlook 2007 / 2010 /2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm writing mail footer (Signature), everywhere it just works fine except of Outlook client! my tables are broken and I don't know why, I have tried lot of tricks on internet but without luck, please, can anybody help? Here is example of my code: I have problems with the part where table is nested in table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
            <title>Mail footer</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                body{margin: 0; font-size: 13px; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;}
                table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
                table td { border-collapse:collapse; }

                @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
                    body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote {
                    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;

                    }
                    table {width: 100% !important;}

                    }

                @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

                    .footer table{width: 25% !important;}
                    }

                 @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {

                    .logo { border: none !important; }
                    }

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="logo">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="550">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                    <div style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 600;"><b>Xxxxx xxxx</b></br></div>
                                    <div style="font-size: 13px;">
                                        <font color="#008AC9">Managing Director</font></br></br>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- white space -->
                            <!--tr><td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" height="15">&nbsp;</td></tr-->
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="24%" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="logo" valign="top" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; padding: 1px 8px 0 8px; border-right: 1px solid #485465;" height="55" align="left">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="Logo" alt="logo" height="40" width="90"></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="7%" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top">
                                               &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="34%" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top">
                                            <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #666666;">
                                                Xxxxxx xxxxx<br />
                                                Xxxxxxx x x xxxx<br />
                                                Xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx<br />
                                                Xxxxxx
                                            </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="34%" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                                        <tr>
                                                <td valign="top">
                                                <div style="font-size: 12px; color: #666666;">
                                                    <a href="" style="color:#666666; text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#666666; text-decoration:none;">Direct: XXXXXXXX<br /></span></a>
                                                    <a href="" style="color:#666666; text-decoration:none;">Office: XXXXXXXX<br /></span></a>
                                                    <a href="mailto:xxx@xxx" style="color:#666666; text-decoration:none;">XXXX@XXXX.com<br /></span></a>
                                                    www.XXXXXX.com
                                                </div>
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            <!-- LOGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ############################ -->
                            <tr><td valign="top" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" height="3" >&nbsp;</td></tr>

                            <tr>
                                 <td  valign="top"> 
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="63.5%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="logo" style="line-height: 0; padding: 1px 8px 0 8px;" height="15px" align="left">
                                                &nbsp;                                          
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <table class="footer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="30%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="logo" style=" padding: 1px 0px 0 8px;" height="15px" align="left">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="20%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" style="display:block;font-size: 0; line-height: 0; padding: 0 8px 0 8px;" height="8px" align="center" class="responsive-image">
                                                            <a href="#"><img src="Test" alt="Facebook" height="8px" width="8px"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="20%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" style="display:block;font-size: 0; line-height: 0; padding: 0 8px 0 8px;" height="8px" align="center" class="responsive-image">
                                                            <a href="#"><img src="Test2" alt="Linkedin" height="8px" width="8px"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="20%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" style="display:block;font-size: 0; line-height: 0; padding: 0 8px 0 8px;" height="8px" align="center" class="responsive-image">
                                                        </td>
                                                            <a href="#"><img src="Test3" alt="Twitter" height="8px" width="8px"></a>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="20%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top" style="display:block;font-size: 0; line-height: 0; padding: 0 8px 0 8px;" height="8px" align="center" class="responsive-image">
                                                            <a href="#"><img src="Test4" alt="Google Plus" height="8px" width="8px"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="6.5%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="logo" style=" line-height: 0; padding: 1px 8px 0 8px;" height="15px" align="left">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr><td valign="top" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" height="10" width="550">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                            <tr><td valign="top" style="border-bottom: dotted 1px #bbbbbb; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" height="1">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                            <tr style="text-align: justify;">
                                <td valign="top">
                                    <div style="font-size: 10px; color: #909090;">
                                    </br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td valign="top" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" height="10" >&nbsp;</td></tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: outlook uses word's html rendering agent, which you should probably consider the equivalent of internet explorer version 0.000000000001cocktail napkin. it's total crap.

Comment: Add to the table style="border-collapse: collapse;"

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the issue is that the tables wind up stacking down to the next line.  This is because Outlook adds spacing between aligned tables.  It is usually best to leave a 10-20px width gap between each table to allow for Outlooks randomly added widths.

Your other option if using a gap is not an option is to use [TD](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/responsive-column-layouts/)s instead of tables. This will remove responsiveness in some clients (especially [Android native client](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how_android_is_strangling_responsive_design)).

If you need to retain responsiveness, by replacing the TDs with TH tags, it removes the issue in the android client and allows you to make the columns stack on mobile.

Comment: Yup Outlook adds margin to the tables that are aligned.  Outlook is awesome! (sarcastically speaking)